# Laravel flash or session messages not expiring [ not maintained Updated ]

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3, flash-message

**Updated after some research**
After some research I conclude that, my sessions are not maintained until I save them explicitly, **below code works well, but WHY????** [Ref here](https://laravel.io/forum/09-07-2016-session-not-saving-laravel-53)

```
Session::put('lets_test', 2);
Session::save();
```

**Old Question**
I'm new to laravel 5.3, and stuck at a problem. My Laravel Session or Flash messages are not expiring they display each time page is reloaded, until I use `Session::flush()` Below is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Session;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Hospital;
use App\Wpr;
use Helper;

class OperatorController extends Controller
{
    public $user_detail;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('operator');
    }
    public function store (Request $request){ //Form is being submitted here
        //My logic here
        Session::flash('user_message', 'Thank You');
        return redirect('/operator/wpr');
    }
}
```

I've also used `Session::set('user_message', 4);` 
and blade view

```
@if(Session::has('user_message'))
    <div class="message  animated tada">
        {{ Session::get('user_message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

I've tried with `Session::forget('user_message')` but no luck.
Updating my post after some research. I've got somewhat close to my problem by [reading this post on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346743/laravel-5-session-doesnt-work) because this question is exactly same to my problem but unfortunately it still persists, I've changed my session storage from file to database (in case file permissions to storage directory). What might be other possibilities?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your controller code? So basically flash session will be removed once its redirected to new URL or a page. Since you are reloading the same page again, The controller again sets the session and is displayed.

Comment: Thanks code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, somehow, I managed to find solution for my problem, of not sustaining sessions. I don't think its any issue related to file permission. Now I'm saving my session explicitly and removing it explicitly. 
Made a Helper class added two methods

```
public static function SetMessage($message, $type){ 
   Session::put('user_message', $message);
   Session::put('user_message_type', $type);
   Session::save();
}
public static function ForgetMessage(){ 
   Session::forget('user_message');
   Session::forget('user_message_type');
   Session::save();
}
```

and within Controller class

```
 Helper::SetMessage('Record updated successfully', 'success');
```

and within blade view tempalte

```
@if(Session::has('user_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('user_message_type') }}">
     {{ Session::get('user_message') }}
     {{ Helper::ForgetMessage('user_message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

I hope this might help someone who is facing such kind problem. **But why is it so, still unknown, maybe one day I'll post the reason too. More suggestions are welcomed, if this could be done in a better way.**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_message'])) {
        $message = $_SESSION['user_message'];
        unset($_SESSION['user_message']);
        return $message;
    }
```

Comment: This snippet might be good with vanilla, but not with laravel. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your (Laravel) blade add `$request->session()->forget('key');` or `Session::forget('key');` at the end of if loop this will end or delete the session of that key. This may help you for more reference about session of laravel 5.3 visit [laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session)